# Python Regular expression look behind for column names

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of column names `['aa_bb', 'aa_cc_bb', 'ff_bb']` I want to return columns that have `bb` but not `aa` or `cc` so the results for the above should be `ff_bb`

Comment: may be this, ``[x for x in lst if not re.search("aa|cc", x) and "bb" in x]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked about look-*behind*, but you could use a negative look-*ahead* assertion at the start of your expression. If the string has any `aa` or `cc` then the `.*(aa|cc)` inside the negative look-ahead will match, so the regex as a whole will fail.

(Putting the equivalent negative look-behind at the end would not work, because look-behind cannot contain variable-width patterns such as `.*`.)

```
>>> import re
>>> names = ['aa_bb', 'aa_cc_bb', 'ff_bb']
>>> pattern = '(?!.*(aa|cc)).*bb'
>>> [name for name in names if re.match(pattern, name)]
['ff_bb']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to use regex.
You can do this:

```
for item in lst:
    if "aa" not in item and "cc" not in item and "bb" in item:
        print(item)
```